# For loop is not returning a different value for every array index

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, integer, switch-statement

I've written a code about a program where a word gets encrypted as a number dependent on a fixed parameter such as "Software" turning into 76389273. However the for loop is not returning different values for every letter, and returns the same value (value of the first letter) for all letters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringtoNumber {
    public static int getNumber(String word) {
        int value = 0;
        int intArray[] = new int[word.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            switch (word.charAt(i)) {
                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                case 'a':
                case 'b':
                case 'c':
                    value = 2;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                case 'd':
                case 'e':
                case 'f':
                    value = 3;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                case 'g':
                case 'h':
                case 'i':
                    value = 4;
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                case 'j':
                case 'k':
                case 'l':
                    value = 5;
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                case 'm':
                case 'n':
                case 'o':
                    value = 6;
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                case 'S':
                case 'p':
                case 'q':
                case 'r':
                case 's':
                    value = 7;
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                case 'V':
                case 't':
                case 'u':
                case 'v':
                    value = 8;
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'X':
                case 'Y':
                case 'Z':
                case 'w':
                case 'x':
                case 'y':
                case 'z':
                    value = 9;
                    break;
            }
            intArray[i] = value;
            return intArray[i];
        }

        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            result += Math.pow(10, i) * intArray[intArray.length - i - 1];
        }
        return result;
    }

        public static void main (String[]arg){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("what word do you want to encrypt");
            String word = input.nextLine();
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < word.length()) {
                System.out.print(getNumber(word));
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried finding mistake but I haven't seen anything, is there something I am not taking into account?

Comment: do you understand what the "return" keyword does?

Comment: oh okay after learning about it more I understood that I have to delete that line for the loop to work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do some progress to debug your program. `return intArray[i]` will return the value of the first letter when the for loop execute the first time.

Comment: You could mention in your answer that `return` will exit the method and will *return to sender*, so to speak

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put `return intArray[i]` inside the for loop, as it breaks the loop at the first iteration and finishes `getNumber` method.

Also you have doubled the for/while loop. As a result, if you fix the problem with `getNumber` method, you will get encrypted word as many times as `word.length()`.

You should either:

- iterate the word in main function and return single integer in `getNumber` method

or

- change return type for getNumber to `int[]` (or even better String) and use for loop inside the `getNumber` - that would be preferred solution

Answer (score 0):

you are returning inside the for loop. So the loop won't continue, and will return the value after the 1st iteration.